# How do you dynamically access attributes of a JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, search, arrays, key

I have a two level JSON object

**EX:**

```
var regexDefs = {

  "alpha": {
    "regex": /^[A-Z]+$/,
    "errMsg": "Alpha Only"
  }
}
```

I want to do something akin to searching an array for a key.

(using jQuery's inArray)

```
var key = "alpha";
alert($.inArray(key,regexDefs));
```

if the key is in the array then I want to do

```
if(regexDefs[key].regex.test){ return true; }
```

I know there may be something funky I'm missing because this is an object not an Array...

doing

```
$.inArray(key,regexDefs)
```

returns undefined

=/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most accurate way is

```
if ("alpha" in regexDefs)
{
}
```

This would evaluate true even if `alpha` was a falsey value such as `0`, `null`, `NaN`, `false`, etc.

You can do the same with a variable:

```
var key = "alpha";
if (key in regexDefs)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
if (regexDefs[key]) {
    // Present.
} else {
    // Not present.
}
```

To learn more about JSON, I can recommend you [Mastering JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)).

Comment: Check however the answer of Andy E for a tad more robust way :)

Comment: A reciprocal +1 seems in order, your method will work just as elegantly if you're certain `key` won't be a falsey value :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (regexDefs['alpha']) {
    // alpha exists in regexDefs
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the key is stored in a variable named key, you can use something like:

```
if(regexDefs[key]) {
    // do your thing
}
```